# Confusion about the definition of interior points on Rudin's real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

So the definition of an interior point of $E$ if there is a neighborhood $N$ of $p$ such that $N$ is a proper subset of $E$ in $X$(metric space). 
(BTW, A neighborhood of $p$ is a set $Nr(p)$ consisting of all q such that $d(p,q)<r$ for some $r > 0$. )

Suppose I choose $X$ to be $[1,3] \cup \{5\}$, and $E$ is $[1,3]$,if I pick $p =3$ , for $r = 1$, therefore the neighborhood of $p$ within $r$ should be the proper subset of $E$. So point $p$ should be the interior point of $E$, but I know it's not. Am I misunderstanding the concept of metric space(from book's definition it just a set, whose elements are points with distance property), or something else went wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you think it's not an interior point?

Comment: If the p is an interior point, then E in this case is open?

Comment: the point $p$ is not a boundary point for sure. A point $p\in X$ will be a boundary point of $E$ if any small ball centered at $p$ has non-empty intersections with both $E$ and $X\backslash E$. In this case the intersection with the complement of $E$ is actually empty

Comment: Yes.  $[1,3]$ is an open set in this universe.  The only reason it seems like it shouldn't be is because it has "sharp edges".  But a sharp edge is only a sharp edge if you can go to the other side and see how sharp it is.  From below and $2.999$ going to $3$ doesn't look sharp.  And from $3.0001$ going back to $3$ *would* look sharp but in this universe you just can't look from that direction.

Comment: Does it mean [1,3] is not open in euclidean space?

Comment: $[1,3]$ is not open in $\mathbb R$ or in any subspace of $\mathbb R$ which contains points immediately larger than $3$ or smaller than $1$.  But in subspaces where entire chunks of numbers immediately larger than $3$ and chunks of numbers smaller than $1$ are simply *not* in the space, then in such a space with the euclidean metric, in such spaces $[1,3]$ is open.

Comment: The easier explaination is that if $X$ is the space, and $A\subset X$ is the subspace. If $F \subset X$ is open in $X$ then $F\cap A$ is open in $A$.  This can be proven but it is so basic it can also be a definition.  And so $E$ is open in $A$ if there is any $F\supset E$ where $F$ is open in $X$.  Consider $F = (0.99, 3.01)$.  This is open in $X$.  So $(0.99,3.01)\cap ([1,3]\cup \{5\}) = [1,3]$.  That's what remains of $F$ once it's cut to fit into the smaller universe. It's gotta be open because $F$ was. The extra buffer points $(3,3.01)$ and $(0.99, 1)$ are cut off but they are not needed.

Comment: Thank you ! It's my first time self study real analysis. Good to have someone like you to make it clear!

Comment: $N$ does not need to be a $proper$ subset of $E$. For example if $X=E=\{p\}.$

Comment: Beginners in topology often err in supposing that properties like open, closed, interior, etc., are intrinsic to a set or point, but such properties are with respect to  some topology T on some set X.

Answer (score 1):

$3$ *is* an interior point.

And $[1,3]$ is an open set.... in this space.

Why do you think $E$ shouldn't be open?  I imagine it is because it has sharp cut off points.   But why does a sharp cut off point mean a set is not open? I imagine it is because you can go past a sharp cut out point and not be in the set anymore.  But if the entire *UNIVERSE* gets cut off, then you *can't* go past the cut off point.  So... the sharp cut off point doesn't matter.

Yes, it's "on the edge" but that's okay because the other side of "the edge" (the numbers just larger than $3$) don't exist.

Think of it this way.  You are snug inside a set if you can go in every direction possible  and have other points around you. Okay, that's way too informal but that is what it essentially means. In $[1,3]$ the point, $2.1$ say, is an interior point because you can go either up or down to get $(2.1-e, 2.1+e)$ and those are all in $[1,3]$.

And at $3$ you can go down and get $(3-e, 3]$ are all in $[1,3]$.  Now you may argue you can't go up.  And that's because there isn't any "up" to go.  The number $(3, 3+e)$ simply do not exist in the space at all.  So all the numbers within $e$ of $3$ are $(3-e, 3]$.  That is the open neighborhood.  And $3$ *IS* an interior point.

A third way of thinking of it:  $N(3,e) = \{x\in [1,3]\cup \{5\}| d(x,3)< e\} = \{x\in \mathbb R|d(x,3)< e\} \cap ([1,3]\cup \{5\}) = (3-e, 3+e) \cap ([1,3]\cup \{5\}) = (3-e, 3]$.  That's the open neighborhood around $3$ in this space.

Anyway, $3$ *is* an interior point.  Just because the universe was sliced by laser beam exactly at the point $3$ and nothing exists on the other side doesn't change anything because..... well, the universe *was* sliced and the other side doesn't exist in the universe any more.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful explanation. However, My confusion is If 3 is an interior point of E, then every points in [1,3] are interior points. From book's definition of "open" , E is open? (open: E is open if every point of E is an interior point of E)

Comment: E is definitely open *in this universe*.

Comment: Why do you think $E$ shouldn't be open?  I imagine it is because it has sharp cut off points.   But why does a sharp cut off point mean as set is not open? I imagine it is because you can go past a sharp cut out point and not be in the set anymore.  But if the entire *UNIVERSE* gets cut off, then you *can't* go past the cut off point.  So... the sharp cut of point doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you very much! I think I get it. Have a good day!

Answer (score 1):

A neighborhood $N$ of $p$ is a set containing $B_X(p,r)=\{x\in X:d(p,x)<r\}$ for some $r>0$.

The concept makes sense when you consider a *subset* $E$ of a metric space $X$; a point $p\in E$ may or not be interior.

If $E=[1,3]$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric, then $3$ is not an interior point of $E$. Indeed every neighborhood of $3$ in $\mathbb{R}$ contains numbers greater than $3$.

If $E=[1,3]$ as a subset of $X=[1,3]\cup\{5\}$, then $3$ *is* an interior point; indeed
$$
B_X(3,1)=\{\color{red}{x\in X}:|x-3|<1\}=(2,3]\subset E
$$
In a different way, a singleton is closed in every metric space. Thus $\{5\}$ is closed in $X$ and therefore its complement in $X$, namely $[1,3]$, is open in $X$, so each of its points is interior.